# Using the same function for different IDs to show elements

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick

so I am still a beginner in javascript and coding in general.
I need to create a survey site from scratch for my studies.

I want to have optional questions which are only displayed when the question before gets answered with yes by clicking on that radio button.
Therefore my html for two questions looks like this:

```
<!-- First Question radio button  -->
<input onclick="showQuestion()" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="rb_pg" value="Ja">

<div id="furtherQuestion" style="display:none">
    <!-- another conditioned question 1 -->
</div>


<!-- Second Question radio button -->
<input onclick="showQuestion()" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="rb_radio" value="Ja">

<div id="furtherQuestion" style="display:none">
    <!-- another conditioned question 2 -->
</div>
```

The function showQuestion() to show the container looks like this:

```
function showQuestion() {
var x = document.getElementById('furtherQuestion');
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Now when I click on the radio buttons "rb_pg" and "rb_radio" for the first and second question, only the first question switches between display none and block.

I know that I am currently using the same ID "furtherQuestion" twice. This is where I need your help.

**How can I pass the parameter from the ID "furtherQuestion" to the function, that I can reuse this function to show the div related to the question which gets answered with the radio button before?**

I hope this is understandable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don’t use ids.  In showQuestion you can use `this` to get a reference to the input button that was clicked, and then use the nextElementSibling property to get a reference to the next div which you can then hide or show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass the id as an argument to the event handler: `showQuestion('furtherQuestion_1')`. 
Further more this is how i would have structured your code.

```js
function showQuestion(id) {
  const $allFurtherQuestionBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.furtherQuestion');
  for (let $el of $allFurtherQuestionBlocks) {
    $el.style.display = "none";
  }
  const $el = document.querySelector(`#${id}`);
  $el.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<input onclick="showQuestion('furtherQuestion_1')" type="radio" name="rb" value="Ja">
<input onclick="showQuestion('furtherQuestion_2')" type="radio" name="rb" value="Ja">

<div id="furtherQuestion_1" class="furtherQuestion" style="display:none">
  <p>Another conditioned question 1</p>
</div>

<div id="furtherQuestion_2" class="furtherQuestion" style="display:none">
  <p>Another conditioned question 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: okay, thanks for that. Now I am able to switch between the different further questions. But I can not see both conditioned questions at a time. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @ycodes If you change your radio buttons to checkboxes as in my first response, you can display multiple questions at once. https://jsfiddle.net/Lz6wrebg/

Comment: @thingEvery okay, but when you want to choose between the options yes and no you need to choose radio buttons.. needs to be exclusive

Comment: @ycodes I don't see any Yes or No buttons in your example. Radio buttons deselect each other when clicked. If you're using a radio button to open and close the follow up questions, then you're only going to be able to see one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, I've got you covered.

You've just got to change that ID to a class (since you can't use the same ID twice), get rid of your `onlick` attributes, and change your radio buttons to checkboxes (since there's no way to deselect a lone radio button).

```
<!-- First Question radio button  -->
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="rb_pg" value="Ja">

<div class="furtherQuestion" style="display:none">
  <span>another conditioned question 1</span>
</div>

<!-- Second Question radio button -->
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="rb_radio" value="Ja">

<div class="furtherQuestion" style="display:none">
  <span>another conditioned question 2</span>
</div>
```

Then use this line of jquery:

```
$('input.form-check-input').on('change', function(){
    $(this).next('.furtherQuestion').toggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lz6wrebg/

---

And if you need them to be radio buttons, just make sure they both have the same name so they deselect each other when clicked.

```
<!-- First Question radio button  -->
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="rb_radio" value="Ja">

<div class="furtherQuestion" style="display:none">
  <span>another conditioned question 1</span>
</div>

<!-- Second Question radio button -->
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="rb_radio" value="Ja">

<div class="furtherQuestion" style="display:none">
  <span>another conditioned question 2</span>
</div>
```

And then use this jquery instead:

```
$('input.form-check-input').on('change', function(){
    $('.furtherQuestion').slideUp(200);
    $(this).next('.furtherQuestion').slideDown();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lz6wrebg/1/

Answer (score 0):

Pass id as a parameter to the function
`<input onclick="showQuestion('furtherQuestion_1')" type="radio" name="rb" value="Ja">`

And JavaScript will be like

```
function showQuestion(id) {
var x = document.getElementById(id);
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Comment: @ycodes This should work as long as you update your IDs to be unique. Or change them to classes instead and they can all stay the same with my solution.